# Sine approximation

Tags: c

I'm trying to approximate sin function using only whole numbers and without using a table.

The function is called for each step. I have successfully approximated it in matlab, but something is wrong in my C code. For some reason I get wrong frequency readings and the function does not work for all frequencies.

```
typedef volatile struct tone_s{
    int32_t impulse;
    int32_t acceleration; 
    int32_t rollover;
    int32_t velocity;
    int32_t phase;
    int32_t counter; 
    int32_t position_acc; 
    int32_t velocity_acc; 
}tone_t; 

static void Osc_Init(tone_t *osc, uint32_t frequency, uint32_t sample_rate){
    int32_t max_int = (1UL << 16); 
    frequency *= 4UL; 

    osc->impulse = (max_int * frequency);
    osc->acceleration = max_int/sample_rate * frequency * frequency;
    osc->rollover = (sample_rate * 2UL / frequency);
    osc->velocity = osc->impulse - (osc->acceleration / 2UL);
    osc->velocity_acc = osc->velocity; 
    osc->phase = -1UL;
    osc->counter = 0; 
    osc->position_acc = 0; 

}

#include <stdio.h>

static int16_t Osc_GenSample(tone_t *osc){
    if(osc->counter == osc->rollover){
        osc->velocity_acc = osc->velocity;
        osc->position_acc = 0;
        osc->phase = -osc->phase;
        osc->counter = 0; 
    }

    int32_t sample = (osc->position_acc / 4194304UL) * osc->phase;

    osc->position_acc += osc->velocity_acc;  
    osc->velocity_acc -= osc->acceleration; 

    osc->counter++; 

    //fprintf(stdout, "%d - %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", sample, osc->impulse, osc->acceleration, osc->velocity, osc->rollover, osc->position_acc, osc->velocity_acc, osc->counter); 
    return sample; 
}
```

Perhaps I'm overcomplicating it.

Comment: Interesting..can you give a wiki or something which explains the approach???

Comment: This isn't a real question.  I suggest you step through your code line by line, comparing intermediate results with those from your Matlab reference.

Comment: You think I haven't? Maybe I missed something..

Comment: @user1953157: There must be a point where an intermediate result diverges from the equivalent in Matlab.  That's where the bug is; build a test-case around that ;)

Comment: I believe you're losing precision in `osc->acceleration = max_int/sample_rate * frequency * frequency;`.  Can you try with changing the order of operations to do multiplication first? For example: `osc->acceleration = max_int * frequency / sample_rate * frequency;`?  You might want to store the intermediate result in a `int64_t` first: `int64_t a = max_int * frequency / sample_rate * frequency; osc->acceleration = a;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Hakmem items 149 to 152](http://home.pipeline.com/~hbaker1/hakmem/hacks.html#item149) for ways to draw a circle incrementally (which of course gives the sine) with very little arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After whole number conversion I arrived at this:

`sample_rate = 2^14

domain = [0:sample_rate]; 
result = [];

x = 2^16
y = 0
epsilon = 1

for j = domain
 x = x - int32((epsilon * y) / 2607);
 y = y + int32((epsilon * x) / 2607);
 result = [result int32(y / 512)];
endfor`

:)

Answer (score 1):

Noticing that all of your constants are declared `UL` i.e. unsigned long, you might try using `int64_t` instead of `int32_t` for your calculations. (Just a guess.)

Comment: ... especially the ones involving multiplication...

Comment: Not a problem, got a kickass solution working based on Eric's answer above. Works great, and with no float math.. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Steve Hollasch maintains a page on using [sin/cos recurrence relations](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/math/inccos.html) for incremental updates. I suppose you could adapt it to `16.16` fixed point if you insist on it; but if you just want to avoid `sinf` calls, you should still use `float`.

It's not clear to me how your code is supposed to work. The multiplications look suspect - prone to overflow; the truncating division surely introduces large errors, e.g.,

`int32_t sample = (osc->position_acc / 4194304UL) * osc->phase;`

If: `(position_acc % 4194304UL) == 4194304UL - 1`, consider the error that has introduced. You could mitigate this by associativity - multiply first, and then divide - but will the `int32_t` hold the result? Maybe you need to consider `int64_t` for intermediate results.

What platform is this for?